# Modeling a gamma-mixture waiting model in BUGS

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs, mixture-distribution

I'm analyzing a noisy time series where  where the inter-event interval is known to follow a two-gamma mixture distribution. If there was a simple model that would generate that kind of thing, it would be pretty simple to implement into BUGS. But otherwise, I can't think of anything that wouldn't be prohibitively kludgey.

Can anyone think of a model that induces mixture-gamma waiting times?

Comment: Psst... you might want to ask a question in your question.

Comment: Heh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gamma distribution with an integer shape parameter is an [Erlang distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) which in turn is a generalization of the Exponential distribution often used to model waiting times. Thus, perhaps one approach is to use an Erlang distribution instead of a Gamma to model your waiting times. One way to justify the Erlang distribution is to assume that inter-event times are triggered by a certain number of underlying exponential inter-event times.

For example, think of water droplets falling into a balloon at some unknown rate. As water droplets keep falling the balloon will pop at some point. The waiting time for a balloon to pop will be erlang distributed as long as the inter-arrival times of the water droplets are exponentially distributed.

A mixture erlang distribution can have the following interpretation: The inter-event times are now dependent on two separate exponentially distributed processes with perhaps different parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Is that an asymptotic result? How high does the trigger have to be?

Comment: A sum of $k$ exponentials with parameter $\lambda$ gives the erlang with parameters $k$ and $\lambda$. Thus, it is not a asymptotic result but a finitary one.